# Почему не работает адаптация на мобильных устройствах?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Вот сайт http://centeredinstvo.ru/ Там есть адаптация, которая работает если уменьшить экран на компьютере путём уменьшения ширины браузера. Но если зайти в инструменты разработчика f12 toggle device toolbar и уменьшать ширину там то адаптация не работает. Почему?

Comment: необходимо заменить <meta name="viewport" content="width=1710"> на <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте в `<head>` - `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`